# X-axis configuration in a plot with data.table

Tags: r, plot, data.table, axis

I couldn't find a solution to configuring the x-axis within the plot of subgroups.
In the a simple example I would like to see the hours on the x-axis which is the core problem. 
(in the more complex problem, the time data would be in minutes, and the number with of rows within the groups would be irregular)

```
library(data.table)

DT<- data.table(ID=rep(1:5, times=6), time=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-07-07 01:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2014-07-09 11:00:00"), by= "2 hours"), outcome=sin(1:30))

setkey(DT, ID, time)

DT[,.SD[,plot(time, outcome)], by=ID]
```

I then tried to different ways. One for example:

```
DT[, c(
   .SD[,plot(time, outcome, xaxt="n"),
   .SD[, axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(min(time), max(time), by = "hour"), format = "%H")]
       ), by=ID]
```

Maybe the usage of `.BY` is a solution or `(.N, .I)` which I dont know how to use.

In the data.table package they wrote:
"`.BY` is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in by. This can be
useful when by is not known in advance. The by variables are also available to j
directly by name; useful for example for titles of graphs if j is a plot command,
or to branch with if() depending on the value of a group variable."

Any recommendation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary that you use `plot()` inside of `DT`? If not,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(
  data=DT,
  aes(x=time,y=outcome,color=factor(ID)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
##
```

[image]

EDIT: How about this?

```
DT[
  ,
{plot(
  x=time,y=outcome,
  main=paste('ID: ', .BY),
  xaxt="n")
 axis.POSIXct(
   1,
   at=seq(
     min(time),max(time),by="hour"),
   format="%H")},
  ID]
```

[image]
[image]

I'm not going to include all 5 plots, but they all evaluate.

Alternatively, you could accomplish this with `ggplot2`:

```
DT[
  ,
  {
    print(ggplot(
      data=.SD,
      aes(x=time,y=outcome))+
        geom_point(size=2,color="red")+
        geom_line()+
        scale_x_datetime(
          "Time",
          breaks=date_breaks(
            width="2 hours"),
          labels=date_format("%H")
        )+
        ggtitle(
          paste("ID: ",.BY))
      )
  },
  by=ID]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd prefer a DT for a variety of reasons. First and foremost it is speed, because the data set will be very large. Additionally I would like to have 6 different plots and not 6 in one. The question also is to make the axis (labels, ticks) hourly.

Comment: @Martin I would suggest that if speed becomes an issue when you're plotting graphs, you're doing smth wrong - plotting millions of points is unlikely to do you any good.

Comment: @eddi, if there're a lot of groups (meaning many plots), then using `data.table` would be advantageous (as `forder` is blazing fast and therefore picking the data corresponding to each group is as well) (and thanks for the edit).

Comment: @Arun how many groups do you think you'd need to get to the point where using `data.table` *for speed* becomes important? I would again repeat what I said before that if you're at that number (of plots in this case), you're doing smth wrong :) (and np)

Comment: @eddi, admittedly A LOT. And I agree on your point. Once I had to plot the gene expression coverage of each expressed gene (~20k genes) on to a separate file for a biologist so that he could later have a look at a gene of interest from his experiments - again there are better ways to do (/avoid) it, but he insisted on it. Maybe the OP does some aggregation prior to plot (all in the same step).. not sure.

Comment: @Arun, eddi: I was using month to date data (14days at the time), and it resulted in 1500 different plots. the speed of the total script (including importing and calculating before plotting) was about 25sec. Sure 2min would do no harm, but similar operations on a daily basis add up to a substantial number. Also I must confess I like usually the clarity of data.table operation.

Comment: @nrussel, Thanks a lot. This is excellent. (Sadly I can not vote up lacking reputation points). I will test the ggplot2 solution for speed comparison in the more complex problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe something like:

```
DT[, {
       x11(); 
       plot(time, outcome, type="l", xaxt="n"); 
       axis.POSIXct(1, at=time, format="%H");
       NULL # let's not return anything, for cleaner output
     }
   , by=ID]
```

??

Comment: Thanks, I have no experience with x11(). I didnt tell that I put all the plots in a pdf file. I guess that doesn't match with the x11 graphic device, does it?

Comment: Just use `pdf()` instead of `x11()`, and you get all figures as separate PDFs. Play with `pdf(onefile=FALSE)` if you need a single file. And I think there should be a `dev.off()` before `NULL`, to close the graphics device (with single-figure files). Not sure about `x11()` but with `pdf()` files remain locked until you close the device (on Windows).